# How to express something opened my eyes to something in English?

Tags: expressions

I am trying to find a common expression of saying that my eyes have opened after something has happened in my life.

For an example: I have moved to another country, learned many things about people, their approaches to living, points of view and so forth. And this experience has opened my eyes/mind widely so I have changed my world view...

Could you please share some common ways of saying this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have been *enlightened*. You have had an *epiphany*.

Comment: @Jim thanks for the suggestion. My I ask to use these two words with a couple of examples as an answer which I could accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The experience/thing/event was an [*eyeopener*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=eye-opener).

1. Something surprising and revealing

-- WordWeb Online

Answer (score 2):

How about ***life-changing*** OR **life-changing experience**? Both are common ways in English of capturing your desired sense.

OD:

> [***life-changing***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/life-changing):
>   having such a strong effect that it changes one's life

Your example:

> I have moved to another country, learned many things about people,
>   their approaches to living, points of view and so forth. And this
>   experience has opened my eyes/mind widely so I have changed my world
>   view... It's been ***life-changing*** OR a **life-changing experience**.

**Life-changing experiences** are by their very nature eye-opening.

***Life-altering*** means the same thing in your context.